# Compiler error C2664 Cannot convert argument with std::make_shared

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, shared-ptr, make-shared

This is rather perplexing; I have a class:

```
namespace myApp {
    class WorldData {
        public:
            WorldData(std::string& environmentFile, bool isProduction = false);
            ...
            ...
    };
}
```

```
#include "myApp.h"

using namespace myApp;

WorldData::WorldData(std::string& environmentFile, bool isProduction) {
    mIsProduction = isProduction;
    // more logic with the environmentFile
}
```

and I tried to create the shared pointer with `std::make_shared`:

```
    std::string environmentFile = "data/environment/hall.json";

    mWorldData = std::make_shared<myApp::WorldData>(environmentFile, true);
```

and this gives me an error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2664   'myApp::WorldData::WorldData(std::string &,bool)': cannot convert argument 1 from '_Ty' to 'std::string &'  MyApplication   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\xutility    158
```

But this seems not quite right because my first argument is a string!  I've tried wrapping it in `std::string`, but that doesn't seem quite right, so I'm convinced there's something a bit trickier going on here.

Edit : copied full error message below:

```
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\xutility(158,56): error C2664: 'myApp::WorldData::WorldData(const std::string &,bool)': cannot convert argument 1 from '_Ty' to 'const std::string &'
2>        with
2>        [
2>            _Ty=myApp::WorldData *
2>        ] (compiling source file ..\..\..\..\dependencies\my-project\src\simulation\WorldData.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\xutility(151,49): message : Reason: cannot convert from '_Ty' to 'const std::string'
2>        with
2>        [
2>            _Ty=myApp::WorldData *
2>        ] (compiling source file ..\..\..\..\dependencies\my-project\src\simulation\WorldData.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\xutility(151,49): message : No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous (compiling source file ..\..\..\..\dependencies\my-project\src\simulation\WorldData.cpp)
2>D:\Projects\myProject\dependencies\my-project\src\simulation\WorldData.cpp(15,12): message : see declaration of 'myApp::WorldData::WorldData'
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\memory(2021): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Construct_in_place<_Ty,myApp::WorldData*>(_Ty &,myApp::WorldData *&&) noexcept(false)' being compiled
2>        with
2>        [
2>            _Ty=myApp::WorldData
2>        ] (compiling source file ..\..\..\..\dependencies\my-project\src\simulation\WorldData.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\memory(2747): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Ref_count_obj2<_Ty>::_Ref_count_obj2<myApp::WorldData*>(myApp::WorldData *&&)' being compiled
2>        with
2>        [
2>            _Ty=myApp::WorldData
2>        ] (compiling source file ..\..\..\..\dependencies\my-project\src\simulation\WorldData.cpp)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\memory(2748): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Ref_count_obj2<_Ty>::_Ref_count_obj2<myApp::WorldData*>(myApp::WorldData *&&)' being compiled
2>        with
2>        [
2>            _Ty=myApp::WorldData
2>        ] (compiling source file ..\..\..\..\dependencies\my-project\src\simulation\WorldData.cpp)
2>D:\Projects\myProject\dependencies\my-project\src\simulation\WorldData.cpp(81): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::shared_ptr<myApp::WorldData> std::make_shared<myApp::WorldData,myApp::WorldData*>(myApp::WorldData *&&)' being compiled
```

This seems to suggest that the compiler thinks the constructor is overloaded and can't find the right one?  Which is odd to me, because I only have one constructor defined!

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/rr3z1WK38 . Please try to create a [mre] showing the error. It would also be helpful to mention your compiler version.

Comment: I'd love to create a minimally reproducible example but I haven't been able to!  I'm hoping someone can point me in the direction of some things to at least investigate here.

Comment: That's only part of the error message. Find all of it in the Output window, where you can see what the compiler has determined `_Ty` to be..

Comment: Why does the constructor want to modify the string argument? Make it `const`.

Comment: If you can't reproduce the error with code similar to where the problem seems to be, try it by bisection: Make a copy of your entire project, and make sure it still has the error. Remove something which looks not at all related to the error. If the error changes or disappears, try to figure out why that something made a difference. If the error is still there, find something else to remove and repeat.

Comment: @molbdnilo I edited the post with what looks like the full error message; it seems that the compiler is confused about the proper constructor for some reason?  But I'm not sure why that'd be with just one constructor.

Comment: Also looks like your constructor is private. Is this intentional or a typo?

Comment: @Meowmere definitely a typo; apologies

Comment: That one constructor is pseudo-two. It will work as a conversion constructor as well (because there is only one non-default argument), and that *mark that constructor as `explicit` just to be on the safe side. I'd also make a real effort to get rid of any/all load-implicit header requirements. Anyway, best of luck.

Comment: What's on line 81 in WorldData.cpp? (It's `std::string` which has a bunch of constructors.)

Comment: Looks like you might have made the `make_shared<WorldData>(new WorldData(file, is_production))` mistake somewhere.

Comment: If you look at the last line, it's trying to use the instantiation `std::make_shared<myApp::WorldData,myApp::WorldData*>(myApp::WorldData *&&)`, which means that your actual code is passing a `myApp::WorldData *` to `make_shared`. And it's an rvalue reference, so it's probably the result of `new`. (This suggests that the code you posted is not the code you wrote, but the code you believe you wrote.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm hesitantly adding this "answer" with the hope of being useful. I say hesitantly because your question is missing a "minimal reproducible example" and compilation details. That said, I have an example with all of the pieces of your failing code that works, so you should be able to compare it with what you have and see what is failing. I made it simple, and placed all of the code in one file even though it is structured to be in two files. I had to comment out a few lines that I left there for clarity. Anyway, here it is:

```
//#pragma once

#include <string>

namespace myApp {
    class WorldData {
        public:
            WorldData(std::string& environmentFile, bool isProduction = false);
        private:
            bool mIsProduction;
    };
}
    
//#include "myApp.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
    
using namespace myApp;

WorldData::WorldData(std::string& environmentFile, bool isProduction) {
    mIsProduction = isProduction;
    // more logic with the environmentFile

    std::cout << environmentFile << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::string environmentFile = "data/environment/hall.json";

    std::shared_ptr<myApp::WorldData> mWorldData = std::make_shared<myApp::WorldData>(environmentFile, true);
}
```

I compiled it using g++ version 4.8.5, but it will compile with MSVC too. Here is the command I used to compile:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 onefile.C
$
```

And the output:

```
$ ./a.out
data/environment/hall.json
$
```

I hope it helps. If it does, let us know what was your problem...